# HeatMap in custom Transfer Learning model in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, heatmap

After creating a model through transfer learning I want to implement a heatmap like grad cam so I followed the [keras guide](https://keras.io/examples/vision/grad_cam/) however the implementation is different since I have a model that is seen as a single layer

The code in colab is

```py
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input, decode_predictions
import numpy as np
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
# Display
from IPython.display import Image, display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from google.colab import drive
import tensorflow as tf
```

```py
drive.mount('/content/drive')
loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('/content/drive/MyDrive/testUnit224E25.h5')
model=loaded_model
img_size = (224, 224)
```

```py
def get_img_array(img_path, size):
    # `img` is a PIL image of size 299x299
    img = keras.utils.load_img(img_path, target_size=size)
    # `array` is a float32 Numpy array of shape (299, 299, 3)
    array = keras.utils.img_to_array(img)
    # We add a dimension to transform our array into a "batch"
    # of size (1, 299, 299, 3)
    array = np.expand_dims(array, axis=0)
    return array
```

```py
def make_gradcam_heatmap(img_array, model, last_conv_layer_name, pred_index=None):
    # First, we create a model that maps the input image to the activations
    # of the last conv layer as well as the output predictions
    grad_model = keras.models.Model(
        model.inputs, [model.get_layer(last_conv_layer_name).output, model.output]
    )

    # Then, we compute the gradient of the top predicted class for our input image
    # with respect to the activations of the last conv layer
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        last_conv_layer_output, preds = grad_model(img_array)
        if pred_index is None:
            pred_index = tf.argmax(preds[0])
        class_channel = preds[:, pred_index]

    # This is the gradient of the output neuron (top predicted or chosen)
    # with regard to the output feature map of the last conv layer
    grads = tape.gradient(class_channel, last_conv_layer_output)

    # This is a vector where each entry is the mean intensity of the gradient
    # over a specific feature map channel
    pooled_grads = tf.reduce_mean(grads, axis=(0, 1, 2))

    # We multiply each channel in the feature map array
    # by "how important this channel is" with regard to the top predicted class
    # then sum all the channels to obtain the heatmap class activation
    last_conv_layer_output = last_conv_layer_output[0]
    heatmap = last_conv_layer_output @ pooled_grads[..., tf.newaxis]
    heatmap = tf.squeeze(heatmap)

    # For visualization purpose, we will also normalize the heatmap between 0 & 1
    heatmap = tf.maximum(heatmap, 0) / tf.math.reduce_max(heatmap)
    return heatmap.numpy()
```

```py
# Prepare image
img_array = preprocess_input(get_img_array(img_path, size=img_size))

# Make model
model = loaded_model

# Remove last layer's softmax
model.layers[-1].activation = None

last_conv_layer_name = 'mobilenetv2_1.00_224'
# Generate class activation heatmap
heatmap = make_gradcam_heatmap(img_array, model, last_conv_layer_name)

# Display heatmap
plt.matshow(heatmap)
plt.show()
```

The summary of the model that I use can be seen below

```
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_2 (InputLayer)        [(None, 224, 224, 3)]     0         
                                                                 
 sequential (Sequential)     (None, 224, 224, 3)       0         
                                                                 
 tf.math.truediv (TFOpLambd  (None, 224, 224, 3)       0         
 a)                                                              
                                                                 
 tf.math.subtract (TFOpLamb  (None, 224, 224, 3)       0         
 da)                                                             
                                                                 
 mobilenetv2_1.00_224 (Func  (None, 7, 7, 1280)        2257984   
 tional)                                                         
                                                                 
 global_average_pooling2d (  (None, 1280)              0         
 GlobalAveragePooling2D)                                         
                                                                 
 dropout (Dropout)           (None, 1280)              0         
                                                                 
 dense (Dense)               (None, 1)                 1281
```

The problem is that mobilenetv2_1.00_224 is being seen as a single layer while I want to take it's last convolutional layer which is Conv_1 as seen below in it's summary

```
 Layer (type)                Output Shape                 Param #   Connected to                  
==================================================================================================
 input_1 (InputLayer)        [(None, 224, 224, 3)]        0         []                            
                                                                                                  
 Conv1 (Conv2D)              (None, 112, 112, 32)         864       ['input_1[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 bn_Conv1 (BatchNormalizati  (None, 112, 112, 32)         128       ['Conv1[0][0]']               
 on)                                                                                              
                                                                                                  
 Conv1_relu (ReLU)           (None, 112, 112, 32)         0         ['bn_Conv1[0][0]']            
...
...                                                                                                  
 Conv_1 (Conv2D)             (None, 7, 7, 1280)           409600    ['block_16_project_BN[0][0]'] 
                                                                                                  
 Conv_1_bn (BatchNormalizat  (None, 7, 7, 1280)           5120      ['Conv_1[0][0]']              
 ion)                                                                                             
                                                                                                  
 out_relu (ReLU)             (None, 7, 7, 1280)           0         ['Conv_1_bn[0][0]']
```

So if I set the last_conv_layer_name as mobilenetv2_1.00_224 I get the error:

```
ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_1'), name='input_1', description="created by layer 'input_1'") at layer "Conv1". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []
```

While if I set the last_conv_layer_name as Conv_1 it cannot find it:

```
ValueError: No such layer: Conv_1. Existing layers are: ['input_2', 'sequential', 'tf.math.truediv', 'tf.math.subtract', 'mobilenetv2_1.00_224', 'global_average_pooling2d', 'dropout', 'dense'].
```

Any advice on how to solve this problem?